# How to prevent authors from editing their post count?

Tags: plugins, posts, author, count

The number of views is something I am very concerned about as it helps me understand how many people actually read the posts. I have bloggers working with me who may fake their article's popularity just by editing the "number of views" in the edit section of each article. How can I stop them from doing that?

I have added `User Role Editor` plugin for the same but I can't figure how to prevent author from changing post count.

Is there any other manner in which I can check the actual number and prevent the author from seeing/editing the same?

They are able to edit here:

[image]

Comment: How can they edit the number of views? Is it stored as a custom field? If so, consider prepending the meta key with underscore to hide it (might need some programming effort to adjust it)

Comment: I have edited my question answering your question.

Comment: Still we have no idea how it's stored and what Edit means. This is not part of the WordPress core. Most likely a 3rd party plugin used here, that are in general off topic. Please post the relevant code, thanks

Comment: Thank you. I looked for plugins and I found that that was actually a plugin that was installed and I made changes from the settings.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a part of WordPress core and it is a part of the plugin called "Post Views Counter".

To change the privileges only to the admin, go to:

1. Setting
2. In General , restrict the editing to only the admin. Check the box.